# Replace/Update multiple field values into a single value using sql

Tags: sql-server

my table is like:

```
id |  name |   subject
-------------------
1  | kil   |   btech
2  | Jim   |   BACHELOR OF TECHNOLOGY
3  | Joe   |   Btech
4  | Ruth  |    MCA
5  | priya |   Master in comp application
6  | dev   |   MASTER IN COMPUTER APPLICATION
7  | sen   |   Master in Computer Application
```

how to group related field value into a single name such as:

```
id |  name  |  subject
-------------------
1  | kil    |  BACHELOR OF TECHNOLOGY
2  | Jim    |  BACHELOR OF TECHNOLOGY
3  | Joe    |  BACHELOR OF TECHNOLOGY
4  | Ruth   |  Master in Computer Application
5  | priya  |  Master in Computer Application
6  | dev    |  Master in Computer Application
7  | sen    |  Master in Computer Application
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a table With Synonyms of the same course. And then join These two tables to get the result

(this might be the easiest way since you can add more Synonyms later without code change)

Like this

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t_Synonyms
(
    SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    FalseText VARCHAR(255),
    DisplayText VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO t_Synonyms(FalseText,DisplayText)
VALUES('BTEC','BACHELOR OF TECHNOLOGY'),
('B.TECG','BACHELOR OF TECHNOLOGY'),
('MCA',' Master in Computer Application'),
    ('Master in comp application',' Master in Computer Application')
SELECT
    YT.ID,
    YT.NAME,
    [SUBJECT] = ISNULL(TS.DisplayText,YT.[SUBJECT])
    FROM YourTable YT
        LEFT JOIN t_Synonyms TS
            ON LTRIM(RTRIM(YT.[SUBJECT])) = LTRIM(RTRIM(TS.FalseText))
```

Comment: @Schuere SQL is case insensitive, so you don't need that

Comment: The *default* options for installation of SQL *Server* will tend to leave you with a server whose *default* collation is case insensitive. That a) doesn't mean that you'll never encounter a case sensitive collation when working with SQL Server and b) definitely doesn't mean that "SQL is case insensitive".

Answer (score 0):

```
update mytable set subject = case when subject = 'btech' or subject = 'Btech' then 'BACHELOR OF TECHNOLOGY' when subject = 'MCA' or subject = 'Master in comp application' then 'Master in Computer Application' end where subject = 'btech' or subject = 'Btech' or subject = 'MCA' or subject = 'Master in comp application'
```